# Magento Customer Group not changing in order

Tags: php, magento, observers

I have the following problem: when a customer place an order I want to change the customer group:

My config.xml:

```
<sales_order_place_before>
            <observers>
                <kat_customer_save_observer>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Kat_Customer_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>customerSaveBefore</method>
                </kat_customer_save_observer>
            </observers>
        </sales_order_place_before>
```

My Observer.php

```
class Kat_Customer_Model_Observer extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{    
    public function customerSaveBefore($observer) {
        $selectedgroup= 5;
        $order = $observer['order'];
        $customer = $order->getCustomer();
        $customer->setData('group_id', $selectedgroup)->save();
    }
}
```

The problem is that after the observer is executed if I look in the backend, the customer group in the customer informations is the correct one, but if I look in the order information, it shows the old customer group.
I tried also to insert order->save() , oddly if I place another order with the same customer, the second order shows the correct group.
How can I update the group when placing the first order?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: how about $customer->setGroupId($selectedgroup); $customer->save();?

Answer (score 1):

You should also update customer_group_id in your order like this:

```
$order = $observer['order'];
$order->setData('customer_group_id',$selectedgroup)->save();
```

Comment: Yes! That was it! Thanks, you made my day!

Comment: I'm glad for that. Have fun!